# How can I match the value of a column on another column to take the value from another column?

Tags: pandas, indexing

My data frame looks as following

```
    time    Weg     Kraft   Adj_Zug_Time    eps     time2   
0   0.02    -0.02771    28.3    1.12          0     0               
1   0.04    -0.0269     28.3    1.14    0.00018772  0.1     
2   0.06    -0.02608    21.2    1.16    0.00015665  0.2     
3   0.08    -0.02527    21.2    1.18    0.00018191  0.3     
4   0.1     -0.02443    28.3    1.2     0.00018107  0.4     
5   0.12    -0.02362    28.3    1.22    0.0001619   0.5     
6   0.14    -0.02277    28.3    1.24    0.00015181  0.6     
7   0.16    -0.02193    28.3    1.26    0.00013562  0.7     
8   0.18    -0.0211     28.3    1.28    0.00015082  0.8     
9   0.2     -0.02028    28.3    1.3     0.00016073  0.9     
10  0.22    -0.01945    28.3    1.32    0.00012887  1   
11  0.24    -0.01862    21.2    1.34    0.00017036  1.1     
12  0.26    -0.01776    35.3    1.36    0.00013887  1.2     
13  0.28    -0.01689    28.3    1.38    0.00013914  1.3     
14  0.3     -0.01605    28.3    1.4     0.0001629   1.4     
15  0.32    -0.01518    35.3    1.42    0.00017935  1.5     
16  0.34    -0.01434    42.4    1.44    0.00022273  1.6     
17  0.36    -0.01351    35.3    1.46    0.00021165  1.7     
18  0.38    -0.01265    35.3    1.48    0.00025136  1.8     
19  0.4     -0.0118     28.3    1.5     0.00027536  1.9     
20  0.42    -0.01097    49.4    1.52    0.00029486  2       
21  0.44    -0.01011    35.3    1.54    0.00031133  2.1     
22  0.46    -0.00928    42.4    1.56    0.00033505  2.2     
23  0.48    -0.00846    49.4    1.58    0.00036787  2.3     
24  0.5     -0.00761    42.4    1.6     0.00037578  2.4     
25  0.52    -0.0068     42.4    1.62    0.00040227  2.5     
26  0.54    -0.00598    42.4    1.64    0.00043238  2.6     
27  0.56    -0.00517    35.3    1.66    0.00044347  2.7     
28  0.58    -0.00431    49.4    1.68    0.00044462  2.8     
29  0.6     -0.00352    49.4    1.7     0.00048994  2.9     
30  0.62    -0.00269    49.4    1.72    0.00050601  3       
31  0.64    -0.00187    42.4    1.74    0.00053589  3.1     
32  0.66    -0.00102    49.4    1.76    0.00054206  3.2     
33  0.68    -0.00018    49.4    1.78    0.00057367  3.3     
34  0.7     0.00065     49.4    1.8     0.0005971   3.4     
35  0.72    0.00149     49.4    1.82    0.00060671  3.5     
36  0.74    0.00228     56.5    1.84    0.00060161  3.6
```

I want to create a new column called `Stress` which will take the values from the `Kraft` column which its `Adj_Zug_time` values will match with `time2` values.

Desired output would be as following:

```
        time    Weg     Kraft   Adj_Zug_Time    eps     time2 Spannung_02
0   0.02    -0.02771    28.3    1.12             0          0       
1   0.04    -0.0269     28.3    1.14    0.00018772          0.1     
2   0.06    -0.02608    21.2    1.16    0.00015665          0.2     
3   0.08    -0.02527    21.2    1.18    0.00018191          0.3     
4   0.1     -0.02443    28.3    1.2     0.00018107          0.4     
5   0.12    -0.02362    28.3    1.22    0.0001619           0.5     
6   0.14    -0.02277    28.3    1.24    0.00015181          0.6     
7   0.16    -0.02193    28.3    1.26    0.00013562          0.7     
8   0.18    -0.0211     28.3    1.28    0.00015082          0.8     
9   0.2     -0.02028    28.3    1.3     0.00016073          0.9     
10  0.22    -0.01945    28.3    1.32    0.00012887           1      
11  0.24    -0.01862    21.2    1.34    0.00017036           1.1    
12  0.26    -0.01776    35.3    1.36    0.00013887           1.2    28.3
13  0.28    -0.01689    28.3    1.38    0.00013914           1.3    28.3
14  0.3     -0.01605    28.3    1.4     0.0001629            1.4    28.3
15  0.32    -0.01518    35.3    1.42    0.00017935           1.5    28.3
16  0.34    -0.01434    42.4    1.44    0.00022273           1.6    42.4
17  0.36    -0.01351    35.3    1.46    0.00021165           1.7    49.4
18  0.38    -0.01265    35.3    1.48    0.00025136           1.8    49.4
19  0.4     -0.0118     28.3    1.5     0.00027536           1.9    
20  0.42    -0.01097    49.4    1.52    0.00029486           2      
21  0.44    -0.01011    35.3    1.54    0.00031133           2.1    
22  0.46    -0.00928    42.4    1.56    0.00033505           2.2    
23  0.48    -0.00846    49.4    1.58    0.00036787           2.3    
24  0.5     -0.00761    42.4    1.6     0.00037578           2.4    
25  0.52    -0.0068     42.4    1.62    0.00040227           2.5    
26  0.54    -0.00598    42.4    1.64    0.00043238           2.6    
27  0.56    -0.00517    35.3    1.66    0.00044347           2.7    
28  0.58    -0.00431    49.4    1.68    0.00044462           2.8    
29  0.6     -0.00352    49.4    1.7     0.00048994           2.9    
30  0.62    -0.00269    49.4    1.72    0.00050601           3      
31  0.64    -0.00187    42.4    1.74    0.00053589           3.1    
32  0.66    -0.00102    49.4    1.76    0.00054206           3.2    
33  0.68    -0.00018    49.4    1.78    0.00057367           3.3    
34  0.7     0.00065     49.4    1.8     0.0005971            3.4    
35  0.72    0.00149     49.4    1.82    0.00060671           3.5    
36  0.74    0.00228     56.5    1.84    0.00060161           3.6
```

In excel I would use index-match for this.

How is it done with Pandas ?

Comment: kindly explain how the matching is done. how do you get the values for 28.3, 42.4.?

Comment: @sammywemmy matching is based on `time2`. There is no match when `time2` equals 1.0 and 1.1 on `Adj_Zug_Time` column. But when `time2` is 1.2 there is a match on `Adj_Zug_Time`and at that point it takes the `Kraft` value at the same index of the match of `Adj_Zug_Time`

Comment: ok. makes sense. do you mind keeping your data to only values currently existing in the sample data. there is no 1.3 (in time2) in Adj_Zug_Time

Comment: @sammywemmy ok corrected

Comment: there is no time2 here, is it now time? where is 42.4 and 49.4 coming from?

Comment: @sammywemmy my bad, column names corrected. it is the same logic, taking time value from time2 comparing with Adj_Zug_Time, if match take the value from kraft.

Comment: cool. no worries. I'll take a stab at it

Comment: @sammywemmy I found there was a rounding problem and because of that matching was not occurring. How can prevent this happening, when there is no exact match but match within some small value ?

Comment: where is the data from? an excel file?

Comment: from a .csv. But I also adjust it before putting into df. I need to reset the time to start from zero.

Comment: hmmm. seems you have to find a way to prevent the time from rounding. Not sure how I can assist you in this case

Comment: I round the values consistently. Now it works! Thank you a lot sammy!!

Comment: whew, glad it worked for you mate

Comment: if it's ok with you, i will undelete my answer and you can mark it as accepted

Comment: yes, sure it was the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps; primarily uses `merge`:

It looks for rows where `Adj_Zug_Time` matches `time2`. note the `how='right`; this means the right column determines how the results are returned.

```
result = pd.merge(
    df.Kraft,
    df.time2,
    left_on=df.Adj_Zug_Time,
    right_on=df.time2,
    how="right",
).Kraft

df.assign(Stress=result)

    time    Weg     Kraft   Adj_Zug_Time    eps     time2   Stress
0   0.02    -0.02771    28.3    1.12    0.000000    0.0     NaN
1   0.04    -0.02690    28.3    1.14    0.000188    0.1     NaN
2   0.06    -0.02608    21.2    1.16    0.000157    0.2     NaN
3   0.08    -0.02527    21.2    1.18    0.000182    0.3     NaN
4   0.10    -0.02443    28.3    1.20    0.000181    0.4     NaN
5   0.12    -0.02362    28.3    1.22    0.000162    0.5     NaN
6   0.14    -0.02277    28.3    1.24    0.000152    0.6     NaN
7   0.16    -0.02193    28.3    1.26    0.000136    0.7     NaN
8   0.18    -0.02110    28.3    1.28    0.000151    0.8     NaN
9   0.20    -0.02028    28.3    1.30    0.000161    0.9     NaN
10  0.22    -0.01945    28.3    1.32    0.000129    1.0     NaN
11  0.24    -0.01862    21.2    1.34    0.000170    1.1     NaN
12  0.26    -0.01776    35.3    1.36    0.000139    1.2     28.3
13  0.28    -0.01689    28.3    1.38    0.000139    1.3     28.3
14  0.30    -0.01605    28.3    1.40    0.000163    1.4     28.3
15  0.32    -0.01518    35.3    1.42    0.000179    1.5     28.3
16  0.34    -0.01434    42.4    1.44    0.000223    1.6     42.4
17  0.36    -0.01351    35.3    1.46    0.000212    1.7     49.4
18  0.38    -0.01265    35.3    1.48    0.000251    1.8     49.4
19  0.40    -0.01180    28.3    1.50    0.000275    1.9     NaN
20  0.42    -0.01097    49.4    1.52    0.000295    2.0     NaN
21  0.44    -0.01011    35.3    1.54    0.000311    2.1     NaN
22  0.46    -0.00928    42.4    1.56    0.000335    2.2     NaN
23  0.48    -0.00846    49.4    1.58    0.000368    2.3     NaN
24  0.50    -0.00761    42.4    1.60    0.000376    2.4     NaN
25  0.52    -0.00680    42.4    1.62    0.000402    2.5     NaN
26  0.54    -0.00598    42.4    1.64    0.000432    2.6     NaN
27  0.56    -0.00517    35.3    1.66    0.000443    2.7     NaN
28  0.58    -0.00431    49.4    1.68    0.000445    2.8     NaN
29  0.60    -0.00352    49.4    1.70    0.000490    2.9     NaN
30  0.62    -0.00269    49.4    1.72    0.000506    3.0     NaN
31  0.64    -0.00187    42.4    1.74    0.000536    3.1     NaN
32  0.66    -0.00102    49.4    1.76    0.000542    3.2     NaN
33  0.68    -0.00018    49.4    1.78    0.000574    3.3     NaN
34  0.70    0.00065     49.4    1.80    0.000597    3.4     NaN
35  0.72    0.00149     49.4    1.82    0.000607    3.5     NaN
36  0.74    0.00228     56.5    1.84    0.000602    3.6     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. It works when time2 index located higher than Adj_Zug_Time match index. So in the sample data, if Adj_Zug_Time would start with 1.2, than the code finds no match which is not true. How can I pass that ?

Comment: Hmm, can you edit your shared data, mix them up with varying positions in Adj_Zug_Time to capture this detail, and let me try it out

Comment: I just tested the same code and it returned the exact results that you expected

Comment: Interestingly, I do not get the same. I get NaN for time2 == 1.2 and some other nonmatching results too.

Comment: no idea why you should be having that. I literally copied and pasted the code you shared. maybe create a new notebook(i assume you are working within a notebook) copy the data you shared directly from StackOverflow, run the code and see if it persists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228832/discussion-between-yirmidokuz-and-sammywemmy).

Comment: i'll delete the answer as it does not solve your challenge. I am hopeful that you will find a solution.